# XSL Check if any child node has text except the one with this tag

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I am having trouble checking this condition:

```
<xsl:template match="//DIO[not(@NOPRINT) or (@NOPRINT != '1')]"........

<xsl:when test="./text()[. != '']">
  <tr>
     <td >
       <xsl:call-template name="someTemplate"/>
     </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:when
```

The XML is this:

```
<Dokument>
  <DIO>someText1</DIO>
  <DIO NOPRINT="1">SomeNoPrintText</DIO>
  <DIO>
      <PODDIO NOPRINT="1">
          <ITEM>10.10.2010</ITEM>
          <ITEM>10:10</ITEM>
          <ITEM>11.11.2011</ITEM>
          <ITEM>11:11</ITEM>
      </PODDIO>
      <PODDIO></PODDIO>
  </DIO>
  <DIO>
      .....
  </DIO>
</Dokument>
```

Now, in the xsl:when test="CONDITION" I need to test if the DIO node contains any text (the current condition is that), but I need to test ONLY from the child nodes that dont have NOPRINT=1 attribute. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this expression for your `xsl:when`

```
 <xsl:when test=".//text()[not(ancestor::*/@NOPRINT='1')][normalize-space()]">
```

Strictly speaking, this would also check for ancestors of the current `DIO` node, not just the ones below it, but it may meet your needs.

I've also used `normalize-space()` here to ignore white-space nodes (although you could also have used the `xsl:strip-space` element).

Note that your template match can also be simplified to this:

```
<xsl:template match="//DIO[not(@NOPRINT = '1')]">
```

This is because `@NOPRINT = 1` will only evaluate to true if a `NOPRINT` exists in the first place (and it equals 1). If there is no such attribute the expression will be false, which is what you want.